# Screenshots of multiple actionbar tabs

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am using Xamarin and C# but I suspect the problem is equally valid in a Java environment.

I have an ActionBar Activity that hosts three tabs each of which hosts a fragment. It uses a ViewPager to allow the user to swipe between the tabs.

The requirement is to programmatically screenshot each tab and then email these as attachments.

The problem is that whilst the ActionBar/ViewPager works well it also optimises the tabs - effectively it isn't creating a fragment's view until it is next in line to be shown. So, if you're on tab 0 - the first tab - then the fragment view for tab 2 is null. So it can't be screenshot.

To overcome this I have tried to set any tab/fragment that has a null view to be selected. This generates the view but because setting it to be selected does not actually render it on screen the view does not have a width or a height value so again it cannot be screenshot (this is the reason for the defensive check at the start of the code taking the screenshot).

So, I guess my question is how can I force the tab to be rendered on screen so that it is correctly filled out and can be screenshot?

My main code extracts are as follows:

```
    private void EmailReport()
    {
        List <Bitmap> bitmaps = new List<Bitmap>();
        List <string> summaryFiles = new List<string>();

        // remember the tab we're on
        var selectedTab = this.ActionBar.SelectedNavigationIndex;

        // take the screenshots
        for (int fragmentNumber = 0; fragmentNumber < projectFragmentPagerAdapter.Count; fragmentNumber++)
        {

            Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment fragment = projectFragmentPagerAdapter.GetItem(fragmentNumber);
            if (fragment.View == null)
            {
                this.ActionBar.GetTabAt(fragmentNumber).Select();
                fragment = projectFragmentPagerAdapter.GetItem(fragmentNumber);
            }

            bitmaps.Add(ScreenShot(fragment.View));
        }

        // set the active tab back
        this.ActionBar.GetTabAt(selectedTab).Select();

        //write the screenshots into  file

        int i = 0;
        foreach(Bitmap bitmap in bitmaps)
        {
            if (bitmap != null)
                summaryFiles.Add(BitmapToFile(bitmap, this.ActionBar.GetTabAt(i).Text));
            i++;
        }

        // now send the file
        EmailSupport.SendAttachments(this, summaryFiles);
    }

    private Bitmap ScreenShot(View fragmentRootView)
    {
        if (fragmentRootView == null || fragmentRootView.Width == 0 || fragmentRootView.Height == 0)
            return null;

        fragmentRootView.DrawingCacheEnabled = true;

        //create a bitmap for the layout and then draw the view into it
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(fragmentRootView.Width, fragmentRootView.Height,Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

        //Get the view's background
        Drawable bgDrawable = fragmentRootView.Background;
        if (bgDrawable!=null)   // has background drawable, then draw it on the canvas
            bgDrawable.Draw(canvas);
        else                    // does not have background drawable, then draw white background on the canvas
            canvas.DrawColor(Color.White);

        // draw the view on the canvas
        fragmentRootView.Draw(canvas);
        fragmentRootView.DrawingCacheEnabled = false;

        return bitmap;
    }
```

Any help would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

The solution in the end was very simple. The ViewPager has a setting controlling the number of pages (fragments) that it will hold "activated". This defaults to 1. As I had 3 tabs this meant there was always one tab (fragment) out of reach.

So, whilst setting up the ViewPager do the following before the tabs are added:

```
reportViewPager.OffscreenPageLimit = pageCount - 1;
```

Or in Java

```
reportViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(pageCount - 1);
```

I hope this helps someone else avoid wasting hours.